# Image in drawable won't show up in Resources section when choosing resource in 'src'

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am trying to set a background image for my app. I have the image in the Drawable section.

I have created an ImageView and am trying to set the src to that file.
However, the image doesn't show up anywhere in the Resources window that opens.

I also tried setting the image as src manually through the XML. But then the image won't display.

The name of the image satisfies all conventions (all lowercase characters, no special characters, etc).

I've used images before but I can't wrap my head around this particular case.

XML code:

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

        android:src="@drawable/weatherbackground" />
```

I'm not setting the image through Java code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: please share xml and java code

Comment: post code that you have tried, It is difficult to answer without code.

Comment: imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.YourImage);    try to rebuild your project may be it help you

Comment: Thanks @VipulChauhan, I rebuilt the project and the image showed up in resources!

Comment: Good luck buddy if any time you stuck in any problem with studio try this or clean the project it will work for you

Comment: @VipulChauhan Thanks, will keep that in mind.